# A way around lack of shallow clone

Tags: dart

I have a very simple class in Dart, which has only 3 final fields, a constructor and one method:

```
class Status {
  final Context context;
  final String carry;
  final int depth;

  const Status({
    Context this.context,
    String this.carry: null,
    int this.depth: 0
  });

  Status dive({
    Context context: null,
    String carry: null,
    int depth: null
  }) {
    return new Status(
      context: context ?? this.context,
      carry: carry ?? this.carry,
      depth: depth ?? this.depth
    );
  }
}
```

The `dive` method basically creates a copy of `Status` with same field values except the explicitly provided.

I just found myself having to write a sub class with just one additional field called `isSafe`:

```
class SecureStatus extends Status {
  final bool isSafe;
}
```

This field has to be included in constructor and the `dive` method. This rises a problem: in order to achieve this I have to repeat insane amount of code just for that one little field. This clearly violates the [DRY rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself):

```
class SecureStatus extends Status {
  final bool isSafe;

  // redundant from here...
  const SecureStatus ({
    Context context,
    String carry: null,
    int depth: 0,
    bool this.isSafe: false
  }) : super(
    context: context,
    carry: carry,
    depth: depth
  );

  SecureStatus dive({
    Context context: null,
    String carry: null,
    int depth: null,
    bool isSafe: null
  }){
    return new SecureStatus(
        context: context ?? this.context,
        carry: carry ?? this.carry,
        depth: depth ?? this.depth,
        isSafe: isSafe ?? this.isSafe
    );
  }
  // ...to here
}
```

It's not even worth to copy-paste the code from base class because of the [little nuances around constructors](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/16090).

I know that [there is no such thing as object copying in Dart](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/3367), but there has to be a better way for my use case. Using mirrors would be an overkill in my opinion. In [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/) I would simply use case class + the `copy()` method. Is there something that can be done in Dart? Maybe I should consider completely different approach, which I am missing right now? Or maybe there will be some feature in future versions of the language, which will help in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think much you can do. A few smaller things

```
class Status {
  final Context context;
  final String carry;
  final int depth;

  const Status({
    this.context,     // remove redundant types
    this.carry: null,
    this.depth: 0
  });

  Status dive({
    Context context: null,
    String carry: null,
    int depth: null
  }) => new Status(    // use shorthand function syntax
      context: context ?? this.context,
      carry: carry ?? this.carry,
      depth: depth ?? this.depth
    );
}


class SecureStatus extends Status {
  final bool isSafe;

  // redundant from here...
  const SecureStatus ({
    Context context,
    String carry: null,
    int depth: 0,
    this.isSafe: false
  }) : super(
    context: context,
    carry: carry,
    depth: depth
  );

  SecureStatus dive({
    Context context: null,
    String carry: null,
    int depth: null,
    bool isSafe: null
  }) => new SecureStatus(
        context: context ?? this.context,
        carry: carry ?? this.carry,
        depth: depth ?? this.depth,
        isSafe: isSafe ?? this.isSafe
    );
  // ...to here
}
```

If you need a lot such classes an alternative approach would be code generation (for example to specify the structure of your classes in JSON and generate the Dart classes from it)